# Get an specific value of a category of a DataFrame Python

Tags: python, dataframe, csv

I wish to append the specific value of a specific category into a list.

Here is my code:

```
amesData = pd.read_csv(fileName, usecols = ['Zip Code','Score'])

listData =[]
for result in amesData['Zip Code']:
    if result==78701:  
        listData = amesData['Score']
```

This is what I am trying but when I print listData, it prints all the Scores in the csv file instead of just the ones that have 78701 as a Zip Code.

Answer (score 0):

change `=` to `append()`

```
amesData = pd.read_csv(fileName, usecols = ['Zip Code','Score'])

listData =[]
for result in amesData['Zip Code']:
    if result==78701:  
        listData.append(amesData['Score'])  # <---- this line
```